# Facebook chatbot add payload for each reply or user input

Tags: facebook-chatbot

I actually have tried payload in button and when user press, it is sent back.

What I need is something like this.

User - Hello  
Bot - Hi, there are the things that I can help. ->> **payload1** 
User - Do no 1. (I need this input to be recognized as **payload1**) 
 
Bot - Okay. I done. Any more? ->> **payload2** 
User - Try one more. (I need this input to be recognized as **payload2**)

I can use either Wit.Ai or Api.Ai. Problem is that language won't be english. How shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook quick replies. You can set max of 11 quick replies each with a different payload so that you get a webhook with that payload.

What is quick reply: horizontally placed button which you can place below your bot's reply. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies).

Hope this helps.